# d3 scales: wrapping when x domain threshold reached

Tags: d3.js

I am fairly new to the framework and I simply cannot find a *simple* example of a matrix that uses scales to compute the x and y of a rect. Here's an example of something I am trying to achieve:

```
w = 400
h = 600

     | column1 | column2 |
--------------------------
row1 | value1  | value2  |
row2 | value3  | value4  | 
row3 | value5  | value6  |
```

My *dataset* looks something like this:

```
dataset = [
[row1-col1, row1,col2],
[row2-col1, row2,col2],
[row3-col1, row3,col2],
]
```

I merge it, using *d3.merge*, so that I append rects. **NB:** The resulting array as 6 elements and not groups of 2.

```
.selectAll('rect')
.data(d3.merge(dataset))
.enter()
.append('rect')
```

**Question:**

What scale do I use so that it wraps on *two* columns based on the width? That is, I would like the following behaviour when *i* is passed to the *xscale* when the *width* == 2.:

```
xscale(1) == 0, xscale(2) == 1
xscale(3) == 0, xscale(4) == 1
xscale(5) == 0, xscale(6) == 1
```

So, `[1,3,5] -> 0`, `[2,4,5] -> 1`.

I also presume this is possible for the y scale as well? I would be very surprised if this were not possible, however I have been hunting around and I cannot find a simple example demonstrating such functionality. I do not want to have to manually wrap (using %) when the row limit is reached. If this isn't part of the standard library it should be included. I wonder how many people are manually implementing this.

Thanks for the help

Comment: This isn't part of the functionality of the library. If you think it should be included, feel free to send a pull request :)

Comment: OK. What sort of _scale_ you call this?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I modulo scale? Or a wrapping scale?